# Can I use "small"/"big" to a noun "sound"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

Suppose that I could not hear a voice from a speaker. In this case, what is the proper adjective to a noun "sound"? Can I just use "small" (and "big"  in the opposite case as well)?

Also, if it is fine, can I use it both in a predicative or attributive use?

Comment: "I could not hear a voice from a speaker" Could you hear anything at all, and if so what? If it was a voice but too quiet to understand what was being said, then "unintelligible".

Comment: I meant a situation where a person can’t recognize what the speaker are saying due to the lack of the volume.

Answer (score -1):

**Small/Big** are adjectives used to describe material things. **Silent/Loud** would be the proper adjectives to address the noun **sound** as far as I know. If you want to diversify you could use; *low, quiet, hushed, soft, muffled, muted* instead of Low. And; *vociferous, vehement,* instead of **loud**.

Comment: Isn’t “low” used to mean the height of the voice pitch as well? So I wonder if it makes a confusion...

Comment: @Blaszard Omg. You're right! It totally makes a confusion. Sorry I'll fix it right away.

Comment: @Blaszard Oh no. Wait. What do you mean by "speaker"? A person or the electronic gadget? 'Cause I'd never heard anyone addressing the volume of `speakers` with any adjectives besides Low or Loud.

Comment: Is there any difference? I meant the person but then now I would like to know the both.

Comment: Yeah... People won't really confuse "low" with low-pitch when talking about speakers. Using the adjective "low" to describe the voice of a person will usually be about their pitch. I didn't realize it 'till now... I've been using low to describe when I can't hear someone properly and now I see I should probably use adjectives like quiet, silent, muffled.